# Как ограничить ввод текста в div

Tags: html, css

Подскажите, как ограничивать ввод текста в теге DIV, что бы просто был перевод строки

Comment: Не совсем понятен вопрос. Во-первых DIV'ы не предназначены для ВВОДА текста. Если вы пользуетесь contenteditable, то укажите это, пожалуйста, в вопросе.

Comment: <font style="width:200px; position:relative;" id="JSt1">fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff</font> хочу, что бы был перенос строки. параметр width не помогает(((

Comment: Много где использую position:absolute; но сам тег font  не под ним, id="JSt1" только для JS там вообще стиль не прописан